# convert (n first bytes of) unsigned char pointer to float and double c++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Consider the following c++ code:

```
unsigned char* data = readData(..);        //Let say data consist of 12 characters
unsigned int dataSize = getDataSize(...);  //the size in byte of the data is also known (let say 12 bytes)

struct Position 
{
   float pos_x;    //remember that float is 4 bytes
   double pos_y;   //remember that double is 8 bytes
}
```

Now I want to fill a Position variable/instance with data.

```
Position pos;
pos.pos_x = ?   //data[0:4[ The first 4 bytes of data should be set to pos_x, since pos_x is of type float which is 4 bytes
pos.pos_x = ?   //data[4:12[ The remaining 8 bytes of data should be set to pos_y which is of type double (8 bytes)
```

I know that in `data`, the first bytes correspond to `pos_x` and the rest to `pos_y`. That means the 4 first byte/character of data should be used to fill pos_x and the 8 remaining byte fill `pos_y` but I don't know how to do that. 
Any idea?  Thanks. Ps: I'm limited to c++11

Comment: Have a look at [`atof()`/ `atod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Nope, his data is stored as binary, those functions operate on text.

Comment: `memcpy` is the solution to your problem if the byte order from `readData` matches your processor native byte order.  If not, you can swap the bytes around and then `memcpy`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Just make `net_to_host_memcpy` function for that and apply it member-wise. Forget about swapping bytes.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: No can do, since you don't know how many bytes are in reversed order.  (Hence the reason there are separate `htons` and `htonl` functions and not just a generic "swap them all")

Comment: @BenVoigt You apply that function member-wise.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: So you propose pointer versions of `htons` and `htonl`.  Good enough, but not to be confused with `memcpy` that can make a binary image of a whole object at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plain `memcpy` as another answer advises. I suggest packing `memcpy` into a function that also does error checking for you for most convenient and type-safe usage.

Example:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

struct ByteStreamReader {
    unsigned char const* begin;
    unsigned char const* const end;

    template<class T>
    operator T() {
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, 
            "The type you are using cannot be safely copied from bytes.");
        if(end - begin < static_cast<decltype(end - begin)>(sizeof(T)))
            throw std::runtime_error("ByteStreamReader");
        T t;
        std::memcpy(&t, begin, sizeof t);
        begin += sizeof t;
        return t;
    }
};

struct Position {
   float pos_x;
   double pos_y;
};

int main() {
    unsigned char data[12] = {};
    unsigned dataSize = sizeof data;

    ByteStreamReader reader{data, data + dataSize};

    Position p;
    p.pos_x = reader;
    p.pos_y = reader;
}
```

Comment: A pedantic note: `memcpy` is not guaranteed to be declared in the global namespace unless you include `<string.h>`. `<cstring>` only guarantees declaration of `std::memcpy`.

Comment: @user2079303 Point taken.

Comment: Your use of the conversion operator is more than a bit dangerous.  It really doesn't "convert" a reader into data.  I *might* do that on a temporary object returned from a function with a name with `&&` restriction, but on some perminant object?  Also, you should static_assert the object being copied is legal to create via memcpy like that.

Comment: `static_assert( std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "The type you are using cannot be safely copied from bytes." )`

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Nice one.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin nice thanks, I'm trying to undestand your code. when you do `ByteStreamReader reader{data, data + dataSize};` it seem like `data` becomes `begin`  and `data + dataSize` becomes `end`  But where in your `ByteStreamReader ` does that happen? I don't see any constructor initializing `begin` and `end`

Comment: @Gaetan It uses [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thanks I got it. Another question, let say in your main() function I have `data1` and `data2` as well as `p1` and `p2`. `p1` is to be fill with `data1` and `p2` with `data2`. After filling `p1` with `data1` (as you done it for `p`), should I clear `begin` and `end` pointer (set them to nullptr for example) because I want to reinitialize them with `data2`. Or can I simply create another  `ByteStreamReader` object (`reader2`) ? [In my real case senario I have a `switch` statement and for each `case` (of the switch) the data are read. So new data comes in  for each `case`]

Comment: @Gaetan You can create a new `ByteStreamReader` object. To be able to re-initialize existing one remove that `const` from `ByteStreamReader::end` and then do `reader = {data2, data2 + data2size};`. There is no performance difference between the two methods though, since each of these are just 2 pointer assignments.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that you can do is to copy the data byte-by byte. There is a standard function to do that: `std::memcpy`. Example usage:

```
assert(sizeof pos.pos_x == 4);
std::memcpy(&pos.pos_x, data, 4);
assert(sizeof pos.pos_y == 8);
std::memcpy(&pos.pos_y, data + 4, 8);
```

Note that simply copying the data only works if the data is in the same representation as the CPU uses. Understand that different processors use different representations. Therefore, if your `readData` receives the data over the network for example, a simple copy is not a good idea. The least that you would have to do in such case is to possibly convert the endianness of the data to the native endianness (probably from big endian, which is conventionally used as the network endianness). Converting from one floating point representation to another is much trickier, but luckily IEE-754 is fairly ubiquitous.

Comment: You do not explain how to apply `memcpy` correctly. Since the `sizeof(Position) == 16` and `dataSize` is 12. There is padding in `Position`

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: There might or might not be padding, the `sizeof` might or might not be `16`.  For portability, best to properly handle padding.  But best not to make assumptions about the size.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I added an example.

Comment: @user2079303 thanks a lot. i wish it were possible to accept more than one answer. Because you answer is also very nice